# When does $x = A_1x + A_2y + A_3z + B_1f_1(x,y,z) + B_2f_2(x,y,z) + B_3f_3(x,y,z)$ imply $A_1 = 1$?

Tags: calculus

Can anyone find necessary and sufficient conditions on real-valued $f_1,f_2,$ and $f_3$ that allow us to equate coefficients in the equation delineated in the title?

I'm assuming linear independence will be needed to make the statement precise, but I'm not too sure how. Maybe we can place conditions by examining the Taylor expansion of these functions centered about $(0,0,0)$?

All I have now is that $f_1,f_2,$ and $f_3$ cannot contain any linear terms, but I'm not too sure if that's even true.

Thank you for all of your help, and be well.

Comment: Well sure, all you need is that $A_2y + A_3z + B_1f_1(x,y,z) + B_2f_2(x,y,x) + B_3f_3(x,y,z) = 0$ for all $x,y,z$.  This is necessary and sufficient.

Comment: That's not very helpful, because the equation you wrote above is non zero in my situation. I think I figured it out, thank you anyway.

Comment: So you have found an instance for which $x = 1\cdot x + c$, and $c \neq 0$?  Interesting...

Comment: I'm just going to say that $x,y,z,f_1(x,y,z),f_2(x,y,z),f_3(x,y,z)$ form a linear independent set of functions.

Comment: That is not sufficient to ensure that $A_1 = 1$, though.

Comment: You can see that what I wrote has to be true; if $A_1 = 1$, just subtract $x$ from both sides, and the rest has to equal zero (this is sufficiency.)  Necessity follows from the fact that if the rest doesn't equal zero, you have $x = A_1 x + c$, so $A_1$ can't equal $1$.

Comment: Just as an example, take $f_1(x,y,z)=x^2y$, $f_2(x,y,z)=xyz$, and $f_3(x,y,z)=xz^2$. Why can we say for sure that the equation delineated in the title ( which is for all $(x,y,z)$ ) implies that $A_1=1$?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "Why can we say for such...", I'm afraid.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84125/discussion-between-user429040-and-jbowman).